# round-off error of sample

Tags: error-propagation

Basic question:

If I have a large set of numbers where the third decimal has been rounded off. For example

$a_1 = 5055.29$

$a_2 = 1755.13$

$a_3 = 1083.03$

$a_4 = 335.99$

$(...)$

If I sum all observations to one number $S = \sum_{i} a_i$

What is the error term for $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the worst case error, the error in each term is at most $\pm0.005$, so the error in the total is within $\pm 0.005 n$.  If $n$ is large, you can use the normal approximation to say the error is roughly normal with zero mean and standard deviation $0.005 \cdot \frac {\sqrt n}2$

Comment: What if the error is small and is equally distributed in the interval?

Comment: The size of the error doesn't matter, that just sets the scale. You can use the variance if the uniform distribution and multiply by the number of observations to get the variance of the sum. The sum approaches the normal distribution as the number of terms increases.